# Is this the best way to represent decades with TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datetime, timespan

I'm making a graph that cover `"1930-1940", "1940-1950", "1950-1960", "1960-1970", ...`

I want to represent this with a `DateTime` and a `Timespan`, but I'm not really sure how to make the `TimeSpan`, and I find it  hard to verify if my timespans are correct.

Is this how I should use `TimeSpan`, or does it overlap? If it's overlapning then how can I fix it?

```
List<DateTime> list1 = new List<DateTime>();
List<TimeSpan> list2 = new List<TimeSpan>();

int startYearInt = 1930;

int times = 0;
const int intervalSize = 10;
for (int i = startYearInt; i < 2020; i += intervalSize)
{
    DateTime sYear = new DateTime(startYearInt + (intervalSize * times++), 1, 1);
    TimeSpan period = (sYear.AddYears(intervalSize)) - sYear;

    list1.Add(sYear);
    list2.Add(period); // <<-- Don't know if if this is correct?
}
```

EDIT:
I have this too. And if My timespan is too small or to last it can give some problems.

```
public bool IsInsidePeriod(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt >= FromYearDateTime && dt < FromYearDateTime.Add(periodTimeSpan);
}
```

Comment: why don't you just represent them as ints?

Comment: Why DateTime _and_ TimeSpan ? All you need is n+1 DateTime values.

Comment: A `TimeSpan` is simply and amount of time, not attached to any points in time (a span of 10 years is just that - it may be a span of 10 years a century ago or a millennium hence).

Comment: Because I have a method that return that a given DateTime is inside the timespan. (EDIT should write period instead of timespan)

Comment: My point is that you can't query the `period` variable to see what decade it belongs to or if a specific year belongs to it.

Comment: I made a edit, to show how I thought I would use the TimeSpan for that method.

Comment: Another note on the timespan issue is that all the timespans in List2 will be identical since they are all exactly 10 years. You might as well just const them all if your interval size is const.

Comment: Thanks all for the great inputs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're better off creating a `DateRange` value type than using a `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan` like that. Look [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html) for an example. You can then have a factory method that gives you a range for a decade: `DateRange.DecadeStartingOn(1930);`. This way, you raise the level of abstraction and deal with the concepts you're referring to *in the code itself*.

Your `IsInsidePeriod` is a simple operation for the `DateRange`:

```
public bool Includes(DateTime date) {
  return start <= date && date <= end;
}
```

(assuming both `start` and `end` are *inclusive*)

Now, if you only need to deal with *decades*, you don't really need a full `DateRange` class, just this:

```
class Decade {

  public int StartYear { get; private set; }
  public int EndYear { get { return StartYear + 9; } }

  public Decade(int startYear) {
    StartYear = startYear;
  }

  public bool Includes(DateTime date) {
    return StartYear <= date.Year && date.Year <= EndYear;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", StartYear, EndYear + 1);
  }

}
```

Or maybe a more general `YearRange`.

Comment: a Decade is a period of 10, your Decade code doesn't work :-)

Comment: @Lloyd The end year of a decade is 9 years after the starting year. 10 years after would be the start of another decade

Answer (score 1):

If all you are asking to do is solve your current issues then the code below works, hey I'm bored, I would however consider doing some research on DateTime ranges, comparisons (especially how the work with different TimeZones etc and intervals.

[DateTime on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int interval = 10;
        DateTime isInRangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        for (int i = 1930; i < 2020; )
        {
            DateRange range = new DateRange(1, 1, i, interval);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: Is in range - {1}", range.ToString(), range.IsInsidePeriod(isInRangeDate)));


            i = range.EndDate.Year;
        }               

        Console.ReadLine();
    }  
}


public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", this.StartDate.Year, this.EndDate.Year);
    }

    public DateRange(int day, int month, int year, int addYears)
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        EndDate = StartDate.AddYears(addYears);
    }

    public bool IsInsidePeriod(DateTime dt)
    {
        return ((dt.Date >= StartDate) && (dt.Date < EndDate));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your IsInPeriod method to something like this:

```
public bool IsInsidePeriod(DateTime dateToCompare, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return startDate <= dateToCompare && dateToCompare < endDate;
}
```

As others have mentioned, `TimeSpan` is not buying you anything and is overcomplicating your described issue.  Pay particular attention to the comparison operators.  You may want either end to be exclusive rather than inclusive or vice versa.